# What is the most effective way of combining multiple flash files into a single movie?

Tags: flash, actionscript, movieclip

I have 8 flash movies, each with 3 scenes within each one.

What is the most effective way (by which I mean, takes the least amount of time to implement and produces a file without each and every object used in the library) to combine these 24 scenes into a single flash file so that they play consecutively and can be exported as a single SWF?

**EDIT:** I know there is a method whereby you select all frames in each scene and convert these frames to a movie clip, however the main document then inherits all the objects from each MC in its library- this seems a cluttered approach. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to put all the movies in one .fla without all the media from each movie appearing in the main .fla's library.

One way to keep it organized is to drag the folder structure of each sub-movie's library into the main movie BEFORE you copy the frames over. If you copy and paste the frames first, everything will be put on the top level of the library which is a mess.

One thing to note is that all the media must have distinct names. If this is a problem, there is a command you can install into Flash CS that adds a prefix or suffix to the names of each item in the sub-movies to avoid conflicts.

Comment: I have actually found that the media does NOT have to have distinct names, when you import the relevant media, Flash CS4 will notify you that you are importing duplicate media. Choose not to replace existing media and you can import the duplicate media no problem.